# How limit the loop to one entry

Tags: java

Below my one loop how to limit to one entry.

```
public ProjectSetup retrieveProjectSetupData(String selectedClientName) {

    Document document = new Document(Constants.CLIENT_NAME, selectedClientName);
    MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = ExternalConnection.getMongoDb();
    MongoCollection collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(Constants.COLLECTION_NAME);
    FindIterable<Document> data = collection.find(document);
    ProjectSetup clientNameData = new ProjectSetup();
    for (Document item : data) {
      clientNameData.set_ID(item.getString(Constants._ID));
      clientNameData.setClientName(item.getString(Constants.CLIENT_NAME));
      clientNameData.setStartDate(item.getString(Constants.START_DATE));
      clientNameData.setEndDate(item.getString(Constants.END_DATE));
      clientNameData.setModuleScope((List) item.get(Constants.MODULES_SCOPE));
      clientNameData.setReferenceData(item.getString(Constants.REFERENCE_DATA));
      clientNameData.setReferenceDate(item.getString(Constants.REFERENCE_DATE));


    }
    return clientNameData;

  }
```

Comment: _How limit the loop to one entry..._ Just remove the loop

Comment: Do you mean  FindIterable<Document> data contains only one entry?

Comment: One way is to remove the for loop and 2nd one is add return statement at the end of for loop code.

Comment: How can you please send me the implementation.

Comment: yes Naveen https://stackoverflow.com/users/3922168/naveenbharadwaj

Comment: There should be a `.limit()` method invokeable on the `FindIterable` object. So something like `collection.find(document).limit(1).iterator().next();` (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to limit the loop to one entry?

`break` the loop:

```
for (Item i: items) {
    // your code here
    break;
}
```

or `return` from the loop:

```
for (Item i: items) {
    // your code here
    return clientNameData;
}
```

or get the first entry from `data`:

```
Object firstEntry = data.first();
```

or you can simply get rid of the loop.

If there is only one entry, the loop will execute only once and you do not need to do anything.